# Query the package in the ubuntu

Tags: apt

We need use `apt-get install` to install the specified package by giving a package name, Like `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.15-26-386`. So maybe we need know if some packages exist .for example. I want to know all the packages with name started with the string `linux-headers`. So far . I just found two commands of Advanced Packaging Tool can do this kind of work.

`dpkg -l package-name-pattern` and `apt-cache search string`.

But I found the results of these two commands are different.
Could someone please tell me what is the difference between them?

Comment: If you are only looking for packages in the Ubuntu repository, you can search the [package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). Also, a lazy way to look press tab after entering some name characters `apt-get install linux-headers-` and tab outputs `Display all 304 possibilities? (y or n)` and they will be displayed one page at a time. Those these don't really answer your question, maybe they can help?

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks your comments. Yeah. What I was looking for is what is the best way to query a package with command in the Ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone please tell me what is the difference between them?

What you are seeing is because `dpkg -l` only queries the already installed (or removed but not purged) package. `apt-cache search` search all repositories independently if it's installed or not, so if you need to know if a package is available you may use `apt-cache` if you want to know if a package is installed you may use `dpkg --list`.